# .htaccess: How to "Specify a cache validator"?

Tags: performance, .htaccess, pagespeed

I'm running Google PageSpeed on my site and it's tell me that I need to
"Specify a cache validator."

The following resources are missing a cache validator. Resources that do not specify a cache validator cannot be refreshed efficiently. Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for the following resources:

... then it lists images, CSS, JS, etc.

According to http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html#LeverageBrowserCaching:

> Set the Last-Modified date to the last time the resource was changed. If the Last-Modified date is sufficiently far enough in the past, chances are the browser won't refetch it.

I have the following in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|css|flv|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|js|pdf|png|svg|swf|tif|tiff)$">
        Header set Last-Modified "Tue, 31 Aug 2010 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is with `Expire:` and not with `Last-Modified:`. Apache would by default send the file `Last-Modified:` header based on the file date. I suggest removing the upper code and replacing it with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Try with that, if it didn't work try adding this as well:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|css|flv|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|js|pdf|png|svg|swf|tif|tiff)$">
        Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 31 Aug 2009 00:00:00 GMT"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I already have things like: ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year" in mod_expires. Any other suggestions?

Comment: try the new `Header set Last-Modified "Mon, 31 Aug 2009 00:00:00 GMT"` instead of the one you have, this one is a year older!

Comment: Tried it, made no difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: No, Unfortunately, the only more idea is to inspect google's pagespeed code and check what exactly it's looking for in the response instead of blindly trying, cuz their documentation is generic recommendations with no specific rules.

Comment: Thanks for this useful post, it has fixed my problem right away via htaccess. Its annoying how the Page Speed lists the problems but then you have to research how to fix them. For the non-technical minded this can prove difficult.

Comment: For completeness: also note that `ETag` is a possible cache validator. For this, one could use the [`FileETag` directive in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html).

Answer (score 6):

In order to "Set A Cache Validator" you need to send the following in your headers:

`Expires` **or** `Cache-Control: max-age`

*AND*

`Last-Modified` **or** `ETag`

So, for example, in PHP you could add the following for CSS and JS files:

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    Header set Expires "Thu, 21 May 2013 20:00:00 GMT"
    Header set Last-Modified "Thu, 21 May 2012 20:00:00 GMT"
</filesMatch>
```

This will satisfy Google's Pagespeed calculator.

Answer (score 2):

I tested all of above codes, But see no change in gtmetrix rank.
Using this improved Cache-Control (Specify a cache validator) rank for my wordpress site:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>

  <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

I recommend you to customize max-age values for your site and it's files yourself.