# Concatenating CSS with cache control

Tags: css, .htaccess, cache-control, typo3

Ok, here's a tough one:

I have these website with several CSS files that uses cache busting and it worked fine. i was getting 403 Not Modified with every call.

But now Im using this rule in my htaccess to concatenate all my files

```
<FilesMatch "\.combined\.css$">
  Options +Includes
  AddOutputFilterByType INCLUDES text/css
  SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
</FilesMatch>
```

Inside script.combined.css you can find this:

```
<!--#include file="file1.css" -->
<!--#include file="file2.css" -->
```

The problem comes that even though my file "script.combined.css" uses cache busting. it's always returning "200 Ok". These are the headers of script.combined.css:

```
Request

URL:http://XXX/css/script.combined.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers

Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:typo3-login-cookiecheck=true; PHPSESSID=2evc53ngjjobateti38gpahtt7; tx_phpmyadmin=quf4sgevagubd1snd9eoq4g4d0; be_typo_user=0f4c7e291b6d7673310d6f15da687910; Typo3InstallTool=62erpih8fmqbbl3pe75pcenuu0; fe_typo_user=a7e5de71521603161fa598ed523b024b
Host:XXX
Referer:http://XXX/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/12.0.742.112 Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30

Response Headers

Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=31536000, public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Wed, 17 Aug 2011 13:56:42 GMT
Expires:Thu, 16 Aug 2012 13:56:42 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
Server:HTTPD
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

...while these are the headers for another simple css file:

```
Request URL:http://XXX/css/style.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified

Request Headers

Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:typo3-login-cookiecheck=true; PHPSESSID=2evc53ngjjobateti38gpahtt7; tx_phpmyadmin=quf4sgevagubd1snd9eoq4g4d0; be_typo_user=0f4c7e291b6d7673310d6f15da687910; Typo3InstallTool=62erpih8fmqbbl3pe75pcenuu0; fe_typo_user=a7e5de71521603161fa598ed523b024b
Host:XXX
If-Modified-Since:Wed, 17 Aug 2011 11:45:17 GMT
Referer:http://XXX/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.04 Chromium/12.0.742.112 Chrome/12.0.742.112 Safari/534.30

Response Headers

Cache-Control:max-age=31536000, public
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Wed, 17 Aug 2011 13:56:42 GMT
Expires:Thu, 16 Aug 2012 13:56:42 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=97
Server:HTTPD
```

I used an extension to measure Page Speed from google and I got this message:

> Specify a cache validator
>
> The following resources are missing a cache validator. Resources that
>   do not specify a cache validator cannot be refreshed efficiently.
>   Specify a Last-Modified or ETag header to enable cache validation for
>   the following resources:
>
> http://XXX/css/script.combined.css?1313583214

What should I do??

Comment: I started my research with this question and then asked [my own question which is now solved](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21338450/131874)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apache's documentation for server side includes:

> In its default configuration, Apache does not send the last modified date or content length HTTP headers on SSI pages, because these values are difficult to calculate for dynamic content.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html

So a direct request in your browser to `styles.combined.css` will never return a 304 Not Modified status.

But if you're setting **expires headers**, the browser simply pulls the asset from the local cache. The request to check the last-modified date is unnecessary and doesn't get sent.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the fine work of the [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) project which gives you a nice base to start of with in new projects. But more importantly it includes a pimped out .htaccess file with well commented rules.

The following snippet might be of use to you specifically:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Expires headers (for better cache control)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# These are pretty far-future expires headers.
# They assume you control versioning with cachebusting query params like
#   <script src="application.js?20100608">
# Additionally, consider that outdated proxies may miscache 
#   www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/

# If you don't use filenames to version, lower the CSS  and JS to something like
#   "access plus 1 week" or so.

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"

# Your document html 
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# Feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"
  ExpiresByType application/atom+xml      "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week" 

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>



# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# ETag removal
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

# Since we're sending far-future expires, we don't need ETags for
# static content.
#   developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
FileETag None
```

Comment: HTML5boilerplate is EXACTLY what im using! And it doesnt work :( That snippet you wrote me, Im already using it.

Comment: Is the css file you are serving (script.combined.css) generated by server side code or put though a script / mod_rewrite and routed to a script? I suspect you use php and if the combined script is made in php and then served you will need to [add a header for caching](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in the php instead...

Comment: I have edited the contents of the script.combiend.css in the post. With that and the rule in the .htaccess, thats all Im using to generate that file. Im not using any PHP explicitly (that I know of).

Comment: No that should work fine. As it stands this sounds like a Page Speed problem and you might want to inspect the request you made to that file with chrome to see what exactly is sent by the server... But other than that I am at a loss

Comment: The header is exaclty where I saw the Code 200. I have written the Headers in the post, so you can see if there's a problem there.

Comment: The htaccess Im usign right now (I simplified and erased what I didnt need) is this one: http://pastebin.com/G2nQZxmv

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641582/htaccess-how-to-specify-a-cache-validator basically just add a Last-Modified header

Comment: Im already using:  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year". Isnt that the same?

Comment: @Dbugger let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2581/discussion-between-sg3s-and-dbugger)

Comment: Well, thanks for all, but we didnt find the solution, so if someone else has an idea, please...

Comment: Hey, I left a comment on the H5BP thread. https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/issues/701