# Conditional request not honored in Includes

Tags: apache, http, include, etag

I'm trying to dynamically concatenate a bunch of javascript files into a single file using the `INCLUDE` filter. The `include.shtml.js` test script is

```
<!--#include virtual="/static/script2.js" -->
<!--#include virtual="/static/script1.js" -->
```

The virtual server config has both `SSIETag` and `SSILastModified` set to `On` for that file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName test.dkt
    ServerAlias test.com
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ErrorLog logs/test.dkt-error_log
    CustomLog logs/test.dkt-access_log combined
    LogLevel info
    FileEtag All
    AddType application/javascript .js

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.com
    <Directory /var/www/html/test.com>
        Options -Indexes
        ExpiresActive Off
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 years"
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/test.com/static>
        <FilesMatch "\.shtml\.js$">
            SSIETag On
            SSILastModified On
            Options +Includes
            SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

It correctly serves the concatenated scripts but is always a full `200 OK` in instead of a `304 Not Modified`. The `Firebug` log

```
Response Headers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 16:57:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 16:53:32 GMT
Etag: "460bbc-5c-4f0ba32b7447d"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: public
Content-Length: 40
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/javascript

Request Headers
GET /static/include.shtml.js HTTP/1.1
Host: test.dkt
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pt-br,en-us;q=0.9,es;q=0.7,en;q=0.6,zh-tw;q=0.4,ar-sa;q=0.3,ar;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 16:53:32 GMT
If-None-Match: "460bbc-5c-4f0ba32b7447d"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Is there a hard coded restriction on conditional requests for the `INCLUDE` filter?

I'm aware that I should "touch" the including script whenever there is a change in any of the included scripts. The Apache version is 2.2 running in Centos 6

### EDIT

Using the [@covener answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21346118/131874) I made it work setting the group execute permission of the file and adding the `XBitHack full` directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you've opted into the etags, it seems you need to separately enable xbithack to allow a 304 to be generated (ap_meets_conditions in the core checks no_local_copy flag referenced in mod_include

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#xbithack

```
/* When our xbithack value isn't set to full or our platform isn't
 * providing group-level protection bits or our group-level bits do not
 * have group-execite on, we will set the no_local_copy value to 1 so
 * that we will not send 304s.
 */
if ((conf->xbithack != XBITHACK_FULL)
    || !(f->r->finfo.valid & APR_FINFO_GPROT)
    || !(f->r->finfo.protection & APR_GEXECUTE)) {
    f->r->no_local_copy = 1;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. From the manual: _This directive only affects files associated with the MIME-type text/html_ And also: _The SSILastModified directive takes precedence over the XBitHack directive when SSILastModified is set to on_

Comment: Only it terms of adding last-modified, SSILastModified can't unset the "no_local_copy" field that will be set if xbithack isn't full and the mapped file meets the conditions

Answer (score 0):

When having

```
SSILastModified on 
XBitHack full
```

together in configuration file, the setting "SSILastModified On" is a silent misconfiguration, because whether "SSILastModified" is on or not, it does not change any program behavior.

By tracking back to the source code of Apache, we can see the root cause of this misconfiguration is that the semantics enabled by "Xbithack Full" implicitly overwrite the semantics enabled by "SSILastModified On".

```
if (conf->lastmodified > 0) {
  ... {
   ap_update_mtime(r, r->finfo.mtime);
   ap_set_last_modified(r);}}

else if (((conf->xbithack == XBITHACK_FULL ||
         (conf->xbithack == XBITHACK_UNSET &&
                DEFAULT_XBITHACK == XBITHACK_FULL))
        ...)) {
        ap_update_mtime(r, r->finfo.mtime);
        ap_set_last_modified(r);
}
```

So one possible solution would be just keep this

```
Xbithack full
```